# Running sequentially Powershell commands in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I would like to run four Powershell commands via Python 3.6 code.
Currently Running on windows, Later will deploy this on a Docker container

The commands are the following:

```
1. $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

2. $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username", $secpasswd)

3. Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Some-Host-Name -port 5985 -Credential $mycreds

4. sc.exe config "MyNewService" obj="user@domain.local" password= "password"
```

Tried search how to do it, found only how to run single command

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(["powershell", "My Command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);

result = process.communicate()
```

Any Ideas how to do it?

Comment: use `;` between commands

Comment: @4c74356b41 Where the "My Command" place?

Comment: Don't. As they are related commands using variable defined in previous ones, they must be executed in the same PowerShell process. It is much simpler to put them all in one single PowerShell script and execute it from Python. If you cannot use an auxilliary script, you will have to feed the standard input of a single PowerShell process with the 4 commands and then close the input pipe.

Comment: @SergeBallesta And in case I depend on return value of the first command, how can I run it sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

Use `powershell.exe`'s `-EncodedCommand` argument.

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(@'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username", $secpasswd)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Some-Host-Name -port 5985 -Credential $mycreds
sc.exe config "MyNewService" obj="user@domain.local" password= "password"
'@))
```

Take this output executed with powershell, and add it as the argument

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(["powershell", "-EncodedCommand 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"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);

result = process.communicate()
```